# Samba configuration for public shares

Tags: samba, samba4

yesterday I upgraded my fedora box to the latest version, and with that, I also upgraded samba, now using samba 4. I used to access those share from any computer at home without user/password, but now there seems to be something wrong with the configuration.

Here is my smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = mygroup
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    netbios name = HOME-WS
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    guest ok = yes
    security = share

[Media]
    path = /mnt/Media
    read only = yes
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes

[Music]
    path = /mnt/Music
    read only = yes
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
```

Looking at the logs, there is a warning related to the security parameter

```
 WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'share' for parameter 'security'
```

Does that means that samba 4 has finally removed 'share' as an option, is there any alternative to it, so that I can configure shares without passwords.

Comment: See the "guest access" section at the bottom of this page. http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions

Comment: You are my hero. I don't believe anyone else with only 158 reputation has a gold badge :).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you follow the FAQ link from JasonAzze, you will see there is a "map to guest" line which is also required, so you need both of these lines:

```
security = user
map to guest = Bad Password
```

I had the same problem as the OP, and I have tested that this solution works on Fedora 18

Comment: Thanks, worked great! From smb.conf man page: "(map to guest) Bad User - Means user logins with an invalid password are rejected, unless the username does not exist, in which case it is treated as a guest login and mapped into the guest account." Combined with a "guest ok = yes" directive under a share will enable user/password-less browsing.

Comment: for map to guest   "Bad User" is better:

`map to guest = Bad User` - Means user logins with an invalid password are rejected, unless the username does not exist, in which case it is
                      treated as a guest login and mapped into the guest account.

As the man page says (`man smb.conf`) users can get confused by the Bad Password option.

Answer (score 8):

I feel obligated to share this after spending hours trying to get this to work under SAMBA4 - here is my working SAMBA4 smb.conf that does NOT require a password to get to the share from windows

```
  [global]
  workgroup = HOME
  server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
  dns proxy = no
  log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
  max log size = 1000
  syslog = 0
  panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
  server role = standalone server
  security = user
  map to guest = Bad Password
  passdb backend = tdbsam
  obey pam restrictions = yes
  unix password sync = yes
  passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
  passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:*        %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
  pam password change = yes
  usershare allow guests = yes

  # VIDEO SHARE
    [HD]
    comment = HD Video Share
    path = /RAID/HD
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    available = yes
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, but I still can't make it work. Maybe I'm missing some directory permission... Windows is no longer asking for a password, but says that there's no permission to access the shared folder.

Comment: You probably also need to chown your shared folder (in his case RAID/HD) or chmod it so it's globally Readable and eXecutable (chmod o+rX /your/dir)

Answer (score 4):

Change "security = share" to "security = user"

Reason: both share and server have been deprecated in Samba4.

Answer (score 3):

I had to remember to do one other thing before I could get this to work... it was to make sure the permissions on my shared unix directory were read/write for the nobody user or the nogroup group. Debian Jessie, Samba 4.1.

Comment: How exactly do you do that?  What the heck is the nobodyuser/nobodygroup?

Answer (score 2):

It work for me very quick

source : https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server

```
[global]
    map to guest = Bad User
    log file = /var/log/samba/%m
    log level = 1

[guest]
    # This share allows anonymous (guest) access
    # without authentication!
    path = /srv/samba/guest/
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
```